# Creating conditional statement in SSRS for linked reports

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have an SSRS SQL Server 2008 R2 Report in which I need to create a switch statement to go to different subreports depending on a parameter value, `SpecialPopulationName`.
When I specify the report using the 'Browse' button the subreport works fine.  But when using my expression I get the error

> The item '/UDS Reports/DSParameterizedDynamicReports/PatientDetailsForSpecialAgHomeless' cannot be found. (rsItemNotFound)

This my `switch` statement:

```
= Switch(Fields!UDSPopulationGroupName.Value = "PublicHousing", "/UDS Reports/DSParameterizedDynamicReports/PatientDetailsForSpecialPopPublicHousing", Fields!UDSPopulationGroupName.Value = "Veterans", "/UDS Reports/DSParameterizedDynamicReports/PatientDetailsForSpecialPopVeteran", Fields!UDSPopulationGroupName.Value = "TotalWorkers", Nothing, Fields!UDSPopulationGroupName.Value = "TotalHomeless", Nothing, Fields!UDSPopulationGroupName.Value = "TotalSchoolBased", Nothing, true, "/UDS Reports/DSParameterizedDynamicReports/PatientDetailsForSpecialAgHomeless")
```

How do I specify the path to the report in the `switch` statement?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out...
Did not need the path, just the name of the report and it worked.